# How to make interactive box plot Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I have Series names "rows" in DataFrame in Python like this:

[image]

The type of this column is "int64" my question is how can I build interacvite Box plot something like below, which will show me max, min and so on values, probably there have to be use :

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
```

:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Box option from plotly graph objects to get the desired box plot

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=rows)) # if the series is independent of any dataframe

fig.show()
```

If your series is part of a dataframe, you can use the following

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df['rows'])) # if the series is part of dataframe, df

fig.show()
```

Hope this helped

Comment: yes it heps, but how can I change title of this graph and name of both axis ?

Comment: you can use this reference from plotly https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/ basically, the 'data'part of the figure is  done here, and you need to update the 'layout